# Send data from HTML to Actionscript3

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flashvars

I am trying to send username from HTML to ActionScript 3.
And I referred [this](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/indexAs3.html) tutorial

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>      
    <object width="100" height="100">
        <param name="movie" VALUE="test.swf">
        <param name="FlashVars" VALUE="userName=permadi">
        <embed src="test.swf" FlashVars="userName=permadi" width="1024" height="768">
        </embed>
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Actionscript3 Code:

```
 function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
  var flashVars=this.loaderInfo.parameters;
  userNameTextField.text=flashVars.userName;
}

var flashVars=new Object();
flashVars.loaderCOmplete:function=loaderComplete;
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, flashVars.loaderComplete);
```

But `userNameTextField` in *swf* file does not displays `userName` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your `flashvars`, you can do like this :

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
    var flashVars =  this.loaderInfo.parameters;
    // verify if your flash var is set
    if(flashVars.userName){
        userNameTextField.text = flashVars.userName;
    }
}
```

Or simply like this :

```
// verify if your flash var is set and set a default value if not, if you want of course
userNameTextField.text = this.loaderInfo.parameters.userName ? this.loaderInfo.parameters.userName : 'default value';
```

And don't forget to embed your font as flash said : "*Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.*", you can see here how to [embed fonts for a dynamic text field](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2661568?hl=en).

Comment: Why not `userNameTextField.text = this.loaderInfo.parameters.userName || 'default value';` ?

Comment: @Cherniv Yes, It's possible too, but I tried to do easy.